# UK 2m Morse Simplex

Tags: legal, united-kingdom, automation

I got my foundation licence and a Baofeng. Just curious if it's in the license boundaries that I could make a little Morse weather station?

It would be controlled by computer and transmit once every 5/10 minutes, with my call sign of course.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, very much in the spirit of amateur radio. Check with the RSGB though, there may be special conditions for unattended transmitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the rules is that your idea would be perfectly legal. According to the [OFCOM terms](https://services.ofcom.org.uk/amateur-terms.pdf) (PDF file):

> 10(1) The Licensee may conduct Unattended Operation of Radio Equipment
>   provided that any such operation is consistent with the terms of this
>   Licence. Additional restrictions which apply to the Unattended
>   Operation of Beacons are specified in Schedule 2 to this Licence.

Basically, as long as you conform to the normal rules (correct band, power, stating your call sign regularly, etc) it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid I have to disagree with the accepted answer and say that no, as a foundation license you are not allowed to do this. The key is in the "additional restrictions" in "schedule 2" of [the license](http://rsgb.org/main/files/2015/09/EX309-Advance-Reference-Data.pdf), as quoted by M6JNY. If you scroll to page 13 in that document, you'll see that no frequencies are allocated for beacon use for foundation license holders.

As for the definition of beacon (page 7):

> “Beacon” means automatic transmitting only Radio Equipment which is operated by the Licensee in
>   accordance with Clause 10 and Schedule 2 of this Licence;

Afraid that definition sounds like it fits!

I'd (genuinely) love to be proven wrong, as it'd mean I'm able to run these sorts of fun projects with foundation license holders building their own remote stations and the like - but it does seem to be off the cards for now at least.